# Object which performed the last ddl statement

Tags: oracle

I wanted to know which procedure or any other object and which user  performed  the last DDL statement on a table .Is it possible to find?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
select owner, object_name, object_type, created, 
to_char(last_ddl_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') 
from dba_objects 
where OBJECT_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

Comment: :Thanks , but if I want to know if it id possible to find  which db-object(procedure, function ) is performing the last DDL on the table.